# Check whether my claim holds good or not.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix over the field $\mathbb C$ and $X \in \mathbb C^{n}$. Let $k$ be the least positive integer such that the set of vectors $\{X, AX, A^{2} X, \dots , A^{k} X \}$ are lineary dependent. Now let us consider a relation $\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i} A^{i} X = 0$ and a polynomial $g(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i} t^{i}$, then can I claim that each root of the equation $g(t) = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector which is in the span of $\{X, AX, A^{2} X, \dots , A^{k-1} X \}$?

I have claimed it. But I am in a fix whether it holds good or not. Please verify it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's called the characteristic polynomial, and yes, its roots are the eigenvalues. Try factoring it using the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: It's the minimal polynomial not the characteristic polynomial

Comment: I think if $k = n$ then $g(t)$ becomes characteristics polynomial.Isn't it?

Comment: I also think $g(t)$ may not be minimal polynomial because we may find some $X \in \mathbb C^{n}$ such that $m (< k)$ be the smallest positive integer for which the set of vectors $\{X, AX, A^{2} X, ... , A^{m} X \}$ are linearly dependent.Then we can construct a polynomial $h(t)$ with $deg\ h(t) < deg\ g(t)$ which also annihilates $A$.Is it not so?

Comment: Is there any certainty that $g(t)$ annihilates $A$?